# Can I produce an area chart specifying x and y coordinates

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to make an area chart in Excel in which I can specify not only the Y coordinates of each point in the series, but the x coordinate also, but it seems to not want me to specify anything like that.

I have two columns: X position and Y position. The X position is specified in a range from 0 to 1 (I've tried making this 0 to 1000 and it doesn't seem to help) and the Y position is in a range from 0 to 1.

I tried making the axis a date axis, but it doesn't seem to want to play nicely.

I'm also trying to add a couple of line charts using essentially the same data to the graph, and that messes things up too, especially if I make it a date axis... Is this even possible, or am I just walking into this brick wall for no reason?

Edit: here is the x data I'm trying to use (times 1000, but it shouldn't really matter)

```
0
97.68840705
182.3748498
214.1227894
321.4202809
321.4202809
390.4061099
450.6768016
491.6432724
535.8516298
567.961026
593.8051742
628.6298548
628.6298548
697.4870999
771.1820801
867.9801624
936.7238562
940.875957
966.2263972
1000
```

As you can see, I'm trying to specify non-even intervals in my graph for each point in the area graph.

The following is the Y data I'm using - I've also multiplied this by 1000 for the moment, but I don't think that's very relevant either:

```
517.6932726
509.7709117
513.765102
530.9302172
500.0990295
548.3594111
544.4642503
690.9949165
501.6835017
500.198059
500.2310689
533.7360533
500.1320393
942.7279329
569.2876477
505.3475936
508.5165379
558.1963425
1000
500.5941771
```

Comment: http://www.keynotesupport.com/excel-basics/excel-chart-types.shtml, http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/available-chart-types-HA001233737.aspx

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not seeing anything like what I'm asking for there... maybe I didn't explain correctly. I'll add the X data that I'm trying to use, as it may be helpful

Comment: Why don't you provide both x and y sample data?

Comment: @DavidPostill I just didn't think it was very important. I've included it now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way of convincing Excel to do this. I set the axis to be a date type, and then changed the X values to be dates relative to a particular date (I chose 1/1/2014). I multiplied my numbers by 1000 and added the result to the days since 1/1/2014 (`=DATE(2014,1,E3*1000)`) where `E3` is the cell with my original value.

[image: Area graph with X values defined]

Comment: Jeff - Area charts compare values between categories.  You can have XY data for each category but the "Area" feature shows how each category contributes.  If you don't have more than one category, an area graph doesn't make sense.  If you already figured out how to do what you want, that's great.  If you need additional support, it would help if you could explain what you are trying to show in the graph.

Comment: @fixer1234 I think the trick was that I wanted to show how each category contributes across two axes - where there is magnitude in the Y axis *and* in the X axis. I'll change the image to show this a little better

Comment: With XY data, the X value locates a position to display a Y value.  The Y values are really what you are comparing.  If X and Y are both dependent variables, it sounds like you have a third variable, so X and Y are really Y and Z.  You can display that using one of the 3D graph types, like a surface chart.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't think that it's necessarily true that anything with 2 dependent variables should need be a 3-dimensional graph. Think of time-series charts for example (which is not precisely what I'm doing but close enough) where the position on the X axis is as important as the value on the Y axis

Comment: Got it.  After you revised the chart in your answer, it became clear what you are trying to do.  It requires treating the X values as categories rather than a continuous variable, which you can do with date/time values.  Very clever.